# Statsmodels.api.tsa.seasonal_decompose plot figsize

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I am using `statsmodels.api.tsa.seasonal_decompose` to do some seasonal analysis of a time series.

I set it up using

```py
decomp_viz = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df_ts['NetConsumption'], period=48*180)
```

and then try and visualise it using

```py
decomp_viz.plot()
```

The output was tiny so I tried to use the standard matplotlib command of

```py
decomp_viz.plot(figsize=(20,20))
```

However, this got the warning:

```py
TypeError: plot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'figsize'
```

The documentation says that a `matplotlib.figure.Figure` is returned from `DecomposeResult.plot` so I am unsure as to why this error is happening.

My version of `statsmodels` is `0.13.1` and I am aware that the documentation is for `0.14.0`, but conda says that that version does not exist and that I cannot update to it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`DecomposeResult.plot` doesn't pass keyword arguments. You can change the figure size after you create it:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

PERIOD = 48*180
g = np.random.default_rng(20211225)
y = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, 10.0, 10*PERIOD))
y += g.standard_normal(y.shape)

decomp_viz = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(y, period=PERIOD)
fig = decomp_viz.plot()
fig.set_size_inches((16, 9))
# Tight layout to realign things
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Decompose plot with size 16, 9]

Alternatively, you can do the same by altering the MPL rc.

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Change default figsize
plt.rc("figure",figsize=(20,20))

PERIOD = 48*180
g = np.random.default_rng(20211225)
y = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, 10.0, 10*PERIOD))
y += g.standard_normal(y.shape)

decomp_viz = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(y, period=PERIOD)
decomp_viz.plot()
plt.show()
```

which produces (cropped as too big for my screen)

[image: Decompose result plot with size 20, 20]